# Flutter - Live textfield validation or validation on char lavel

Tags: flutter, validation, textfield, livevalidation

I am not able to find how can I add live validation in flutter textfield. I want to show error message only when particular char is mismatch and not as soon as I start typing in textfield. I am trying to achieve something similar to Google Pay Bank Account link. Please check the below video to understand what I am trying to achieve.

I am not fully sure But we may achieve this using regex.

[Screen Recording  of expected output](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNapuztZiapeq1TkYfNrp3d0IqDgfCNYetJx3ie_AFTQ73nUmNQi-lprhzIo4Cdrw/photo/AF1QipPpE5htyg5HTUgyNANYbSC5oZfTT9fOBAUBSxp6?key=UHBPVDF4MENjbFlRbW5NMi1oTWR4aWR6UnpFbUJ3)

Comment: Can you share some code ? Did you use this : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation#3-create-a-button-to-validate-and-submit-the-form

Answer (score 0):

if i really understand what are you trying to do , you want to do a live validation on text input , i consider you use this package `form_bloc`, you can check [this](https://giancarlocode.github.io/form_bloc/#/) for some examples .

Hope that hepls

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this functionality by `startsWith()` method available in dart.